# Get elements of same name from XML using XQuery in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I am having following XML

```
DECLARE @ruleXML XML
SET @RuleXML = '<questionnaire xmlns:xsi="http://schema1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schem2" title="Sample">
  <sections>
    <section id="24" title="Section Title" help="" url="">
      <questions />
    </section>
    <section id="23" title="Information" help="" url="">
      <questions />
    </section>
    <section id="25" title="Section Title1" help="" url="">
      <questions>
        <question id="3" title="Question Text">
          <display-rules />
          <questions />
        </question>
        <question id="4" title="Question Text" >
          <response-set type="inline" />
          <display-rules />
          <questions />
        </question>
      </questions>
    </section>
  </sections>
</questionnaire>'
```

How to get a table with question id and title from all the question nodes regardless of their level using XQUERY in SQL server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
; with  xmlnamespaces (default 'http://schem2')
select  tbl.col1.value('@id', 'int')
,       tbl.col1.value('@title', 'varchar(100)')
from    @RuleXML.nodes('//question') tbl(col1)
```

[Working example at SQL FIddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/234/0)